# Rails generate creates files in wrong folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

when I run a command like `rails generate model Address` Rails creates the model file and the migration file inside the `config` folder. A lot of other things are broken too. E.g. I can't launch the server because the configuration file `config.ru` cannot be found.

What's wrong here and how can I fix this?

I guess some paths are set incorrectly. But I wonder how that could happen because I haven't touched anything since yesterday evening.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
# in your development.rb file write this
config.paths['db/migrate'] += 'db/migrate/'
```

then run

```
rails generate model Address
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But I still can't launch the server and basically do nothing on the command line. Isn't this a more fundamental problem? Maybe I should create a new Rails app from scratch?

Comment: Ahh ok, got it. Apparently I had accidentally moved the `config.ru` file into the `config` folder yesterday evening. Silly me... I shouldn't work more than 8 hours a day...